# Equations of motion for certain representation of the force

Tags: closed-form, classical-mechanics, integrable-systems

This might seem like an easy question, I would appreciate any help you can provide.

For the force F can be factored as below, is the equation of motion (EOM) integrable?

a) $F\left({x}_{i},t\right)=f\left({x}_{i}\right)g\left(t\right)$

b) $F\left(\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left({x}_{i}\right),t\right)=f\left(\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left({x}_{i}\right)\right)g\left(t\right)$

c) $F\left(\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left({x}_{i}\right),{x}_{i}\right)=f\left({x}_{i}\right)g\left(\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left({x}_{i}\right)\right)$

My attempt:

a) EOM not integrable (why though? how can I be sure?)

b) $m\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left(\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left({x}_{i}\right)\right)=f\left(\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left({x}_{i}\right)\right)g\left(t\right)=>m\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{1}{f\left(\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left({x}_{i}\right)\right)}}d\left(\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left({x}_{i}\right)\right)=\displaystyle\int{g\left(t\right)}dt$

c) $m\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left(\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left({x}_{i}\right)\right)=g\left(\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left({x}_{i}\right)\right)f\left({x}_{i}\right)=>m\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left({x}_{i}\right)}{g\left(\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left({x}_{i}\right)\right)}}d\left(\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left({x}_{i}\right)\right)=\displaystyle\int{f\left({x}_{i}\right)}d\left({x}_{i}\right)$

Is this correct? What is the point of the exercise?  Is there an analytical way to prove the equation of motion can't be integrated?

Answer (score 0):

You can't integrate a) because in the the right hand side there is $f=f(x_i)$ and you've got a differential on $t$. If you rearrange terms, you can verify that
$$m\frac{\mathrm d\dot{x_i}}{f(x_i)}=g(t)\,\mathrm dt$$
so that now you can't integrate the left hand side because $f$ depends un $x_i$ and you've got a differential on $\dot{x}_i$.

For b) you can integrate because each side has got the right variable
$$m\frac{\mathrm d\dot{x_i}}{f(\dot x_i)}=g(t)\,\mathrm dt$$

For c) you cannot integrate because $f$ depends un $x_i$ and you've got a differential on $t$.
$$m\frac{\mathrm d\dot{x_i}}{g(\dot x_i)}=f(x_i)\,\mathrm dt$$